# Position of annotations on a pdf document

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, pdf-annotations

I need to add some text annotations on an existing pdf. I managed to create the annotations and display them. The only problem is that when a pdf document is opened in Adobe Reader, the content of the annotation (in case it maximized) is displayed in the right part of the page.

It is possible to set the coordinates of the expanded annotation to be the same as the icon?
(I'm using itext 5 to manipulate pdfs)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to do this with iText, but I can tell you how it works internally in the PDF format.

Annotation objects can have a *Popup* attribute that customizes the popup window associated to the annotation. This *Popup* attribute is also an annotation object, so you can configure its possition on the page the same way you configured the parent anotation.

From the [PDF Reference Document](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf&ei=R1uZT5fvBaiI6AH26-nzBg&usg=AFQjCNHj0opL138bjrVRNI7cKXQXC2Xg4Q):

**TABLE 8.15 Entries common to all annotation dictionaries**
**Key:** *Rect*
**Type:** *rectangle*
**Value:** *(Required) The annotation rectangle, defining the location of the annotation on the page in default user space units.*

There are different types of annotations in PDF (Text, Link, FreeText, Line, Square, etc) but only markup annotations can have a popup window, and not all these types are considered as markup annotations. If you want to know which types are considered markup annotations take a look on *TABLE 8.20 Annotation types* of the PDF Reference document (Chapter 8 - Annotations, part 8.4.5 - Annotation types).
Looking at iText documentation, I saw there is a class called [PdfAnnotation](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfAnnotation.html), this is probably the class you are using for creating your new annotation. This class contains a method called [setPopup](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfAnnotation.html#setPopup%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation%29). Maybe you could give this method a try.